# Dropt down menu hiding behind div

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using below code and don't know which part has an error.

- Header
- Body
- Footer

The issue is that the header part menu can't display over the body part. Which means, body part is over the head menu.

Body part CSS is not here. I've been trying z-index position etc. But I guess I used wrong way and can't figure it out.

```css
     ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25px;
         color: #1a1a1a;
         text-align:left;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
         }

        li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;

        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
         }
```

```html
<table class="header" style="border:none;"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100px">
     <tr>
     <td> <a href="#####"><img src="123.png"/></a></td>
      <td style="border:none;" width="50%">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="####"><b>Home</b></a></li>
     
     <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropbtn"><b>ABC</b></a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="abc-1"><b>abc-1</b></a>
       <a href="abc-2"><b>abc-2</b></a>
       <a href="abc-3"><b>abc-3</b></a>
     </div>
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn"><b>DEF</b></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">  
       <a href="def-1"><b>def-1</b></a>
       <a href="def-2"><b>def-2</b></a>
      </div>
     </li>
        </ul>
        </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for making my question clear. :-)